# Git pre-merge-commit hook : How do I ignore a file during a merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, githooks

## Context

I'm working in a complex git flow where some specific branches get specific submodules and some specific config files that require to be committed, but must not be merged.

These are few files but it is too dangerous to let anyone merge branches without being careful not to merge those.

In order to make it automatic, I worked on pre-merge-commit hooks, both at server and local side.

In case of conflict, I make use of `.gitattributes` and `git/config` files to resolve the conflict with a custom merge driver. It works like a charm.

## Problem

However, I'm struggling to make it work when there is no conflict. In this case, the merge is carried out successfully and my pre-merge-hook is triggered. It does its magic and then exit successfully. Though, for some reason, git re-do some merging stuff after the hook which make it useless. Here is the behavior I'm witnessing :

**before the merge**

I got two branches, let's say `A_current` and `B_incoming`.

Both got a file I don't want to be merged. This file is called `do_not_merge_me`. At some point, `do_not_merge_me` content changed in `B_incoming`. Let's say it went from `contentA` to `contentB`

**during the merge**

What I see when I'm merging `B_incoming` into `A_current` is :

- The merge goes on, and adds files in the staged area, including `do_not_merge_me`.
- The merge succeed, so it triggers my hook
- my hook finds `do_not_merge_me` in the staging area and remove it from the staging area (at the end, it's a `git reset do_not_merge_me` followed by a `git checkout do_not_merge_me`)
- my hook ends properly, `do_not_merge_me` is not in the staging area anymore
- Git does some dark magic : it redo a merge and re-stage `do_not_merge_me`
- Git validate the commit, I see this added in my console :

```
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 do_not_merge_me               | 2 +-
```

- Weirdly, after the merge is done, I got the correct versions of the files in my staged area (I'd never seen anything in the staging area after a merge, before this)

## Question

The git documentation, available here https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_merge_commit, states the pre-merge-commit is triggered after the merged is successfully handled and before the commit is validated.

My questions are:

1. why do I get the correct version in the staged area ?
2. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?
3. Why is git doing some merging stuff after the hook ? Is it a bug ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

When `git merge` runs, it reads three commits into Git's *index*.  These three commits are:

- the merge base (in slot 1);
- the `--ours` commit (in slot 2); and
- the `--theirs` commit (in slot 3).

These are stored in the usual index format: a path name including slashes, a `mode` (100644 or 100755 for regular files, 120000 for symbolic links, and 160000 for gitlinks), and a hash ID.

The first part of the merge then compares the modes to make sure those are suitable (if not, this is a merge conflict).  Assuming normal files and suitable modes here, it goes on to compare the hash IDs:

- all three equal? file is successfully merged, drop to slot 0, erase slots 1-3
- two equal? take the third one: drop to slot 0, erase slots 1-3
- all three unequal? leave for later, for the real merge code.

There are a few more special cases (e.g., file exists in merge base and theirs/ours, but deleted in ours/theirs) that are also handled directly in the index, I think, but your particular case—file modified in `theirs`, but identical in `ours` and base—hits the middle "two equal? take third" case: the file is the same in your commit and the merge base, so Git just *assumes* that their updated file is the correct result.

*When Git does this in the early pass*, it never runs your merge driver at all.  The file goes to staging slot zero—"ready to be committed"—rather than conflicted and you never get a chance to do anything.  Your *pre-merge-commit* will get invoked, but the copy of the file in the index will be the one from the `theirs` commit.

We now get into the seriously dark magic part: "the index" assumes that there's a single index (`.git/index`) that is always used.  This isn't really the case: it's *mostly* true, but:

- `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` overrides the name;
- added work-trees (from `git worktree add`) have their own index; and
- various Git commands read the index into memory and then work with that.

In this case, it looks like `git merge` has the index in-memory and just uses it as is to make the new commit.  Your `git add` replaces the stage-zero copy in the `.git/index` file, but `git merge` does not notice this, and goes on to produce the new merge commit using the incoming copy that was there before it even ran your pre-merge-commit hook.

Assuming this is all true—and it may change from one Git version to another, depending on when and whether Git does any re-reading of the index—this would answer your question #1, and render the answer to #2 "no" and the answer to #3 be "you're trying to do something outside the range of what Git handles".

What you want to do is not inherently unreasonable, but Git just doesn't support it.

Comment: #1 I'm never doing any `git add` in the hook though, do you understand why I'm still getting it in the staged area after the whole merge completes ?
#3 So, If I understand properly, there is another space, probably in memory, where "ready-to-merge" files are handled : which mean no external access from the hook.

Comment: At this point, I got 2 other questions popping up :

**#4** For now the only solution I see is to invoke a post-merge hook to do a `git commit --amend` to add the staged files in the merge afterward. Is this allowed by the hook ?
**#5** I know this sounds tricky, but I noticed, if I exit with an error at the end of my pre-merge-commit hook, the staged area looks like what I want it to be. Is there a way to trigger a hook or something to end the merge on pre-merge-commit failure ?

Comment: #1: If your hook is not running `git add`, what *is* it running? #2: there is no #2, I guess. #3: by the time your pre-merge-commit hook runs, the merge is all done anyway. Note that [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) points out that the pre-merge-commit hook is only run if the merge is considered successful: if the merge stops in the middle with a conflict, it's never run.

Comment: #4: the post-merge hook was designed to allow you to `chmod` files in your working tree, but it does look like you can make changes to Git's index safely, at this point. Actually running `git commit` from this hook is probably not a great idea (creating new commits in *any* hook is going to be tricky because of the possibility of having Git environment variables set).  For #5: exiting nonzero from the pre-merge-commit hook will prevent creation of the merge commit; that's documented, so it's reliable.

Comment: **#1** The hook is not running git add, instead it unstages files with `git reset` and `git checkout`

Comment: **#4** Could you point me to somewhere I can read about this Git environment variables issues ? It feels like in my case, running a git commit from about anywhere (meaning different terminal/environment variables) never have been an issue

Comment: **#5** So it's reliable in the way it behaves, though it won't let me trigger anything automatically afterward. The idea would be to create exit on purpose and then trigger a git commit

Comment: Ah, right. `git reset` means meany things depending on how you invoke it; in this case, probably *modify the index by reading from the current commit*. Meanwhile `git checkout` of a specific file, not given any commit hash ID, means *copy from index to working tree*. Since `HEAD` has not yet been updated you could simplify this as `git checkout HEAD -- <path>` which would copy from the current commit to both index and working tree. Re #4, this isn't described very well anywhere that I know other than various blogs and SO postings, but if `$GIT_INDEX_FILE` is set, that's the name of the index.

Answer (score 1):

So to anyone who need to apply changes during a merge, here is the solution I came with.

> keep in mind this solution can possibly create some issues in some corner cases as pointed by @torek in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67590221/git-pre-merge-commit-hook-how-do-i-ignore-a-file-during-a-merge/67595693#comment119507222_67595693).

> Most of the time, you want to avoid doing modifications at merge. Prefer verification.

Those steps work well for me with my version of git (`2.31.1`). I don't know if this behavior is consistent across versions.

1. Implement a custom merge strategy using `.gitattributes` for the files you need to modify. It must apply those modifications. This does the same thing than step 3, but in case of conflict on the targeted files
2. Implement a pre-merge-commit hook. This will be triggered after conflicts are solved. This mean you will have access to a staged area that mirrors the merge result.
3. Modify the staged area: Using your pre-merge-commit hook, you can modify your staged area, this won't actually modify the merge outcome (which is stored somewhere else). Instead, when your script will successfully exit, your modifications will get in the staged area. This is the first time I see something left in the staged area after a merge.

> Note : The reason why it does that is git seems to initiate a second merge

4. Finally, you need to implement a post-merge hook to amend the merge commit with the actual staged area content. You need to delete the file `.git/MERGE_HEAD` before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this need by myself, and **I managed to solve it** with a git alias.

#### I published it on [this repository](https://github.com/taljacob2/git-merge-and-ignore), so you can use it too.

You are very welcome to add your own ideas to it for future updates and contribute.